# QT QML inputMethodHints

Tags: qt, namespaces, qml

My question is related to the inputMethodHints 
**https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop**

All this flags work perfectly, and there is nothing to complain about. But I found two flags more, and in my situation it is very necessary to use them. 
**https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#InputMethodHint-enum**

**Qt::ImhNoEditMenu and Qt::ImhNoTextHandles.**

I haven't found, how to use this flags, maybe some one can help me? I tried to use this flags inside the TextInput, TextArea, TextEdit and TextField in the qml code, setting for example 
`inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoTextHandles`

But they doesn't work. Also they are not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, only in the webpage(Qt namespaces) what I linked above. Thanks for attention, hope that someone can help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: `Qt::ImhNoEditMenu` - Do not use built-in edit menu.
`Qt::ImhNoTextHandles` - Do not use built-in text cursor and selection handles.  Just copied from the docs. But what is your _real_ target? Please clarify the question.

Comment: My real target is to disable android inbuild native text selection menu and text selection cursors.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for it, then don't. At the moment this flags are not integrated and are not able to be used.